# How do we calculate the rotation of 3D vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, vector-spaces

Consider three vectors as 3D axis in a unit sphere:

$$A = (1,0,0)$$
$$B = (0,1,0)$$
$$C = (0,0,1)$$

If we rotate the sphere around y-axis by $\theta$ and then around the x-axis by $\phi$. How do we calculate the new vectors?

I came up with a solution of

$$A_x = \cos(\theta)$$
$$A_y = 0 $$
$$A_z = \sin(\theta)$$
$$B_x = \sin(\theta) . \sin(\phi) $$
$$B_y = \cos(\theta) . \cos(\phi) $$
$$B_z = \cos(\theta) . \sin(\phi) $$

Although I got some correct results, I can tell my approach is incorrect.

Comment: Everything is correct except $B_y$ and $B_z$. See @Flutterblaxi's answer.

Comment: No, the columns of $M$ are the images of $A$, $B$, $C$, so $A_y$, $A_z$ and $B_x$ are also incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation you're describing is the composition of two rotations, $R_y(\theta)$ and $R_x(\phi)$. So the associated matrix $M$ is the product of these two matrices:
$$M= R_x(\phi) R_y(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&\cos(\phi)&-\sin(\phi) \\ 0&\sin(\phi)&\cos(\phi)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta)&0&\sin(\theta)\\0&1&0\\-\sin(\theta)&0&\cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta)&0&\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)&\cos(\phi)&-\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta) \\ -\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta)&\sin(\phi)&\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta) \end{pmatrix}$$

The columns of $M$ are the new vectors $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Comment: -@Flutterblaxi, the signs of $\sin \theta$ should be inverted in $R_y(\theta) $.

Comment: @Doubtnut Right, I'm correcting it (while crying), thanks

Comment: So, you got $A_z$ and $B_x$ -ve of OP's answer.